# Formula for Multiplicities of Weights in Tensor Powers of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\Bbb{C})$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, characters

Let $V=\Bbb{C}^3$ denote the standard representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\Bbb{C})$. We can produce the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\Bbb{C})$ of a given highest weight by using the tensor powers $\mathrm{Sym}^a(V)\otimes \mathrm{Sym}^b(V^*).$

In *Representation Theory, A First Course* by Fulton and Harris, on p.184 there is a claim that in the representation $\mathrm{Sym}^a(V)\otimes \mathrm{Sym}^b(V^*)$ the weight multiplicities are given by $(i+1)(i+2)/2$ on the hexagon $H_i$ and given by the constant multiplicities $(b+1)(b+2)/2$ on the triangles $T_j$, as in the figure below: [image]

Here, $H_0$ denotes the outermost hexagon. There are thus two hexagons $H_0$ and $H_1$. The triangles then denote the $2$ inner layers, $T_0$ and $T_1$.

> Being somewhat combinatorially impaired, I was hoping that someone might suggest to me a strategy for deriving these formulas.

I have tried working out some small examples, but the calculations become too immense before I can really see the pattern in a meaningful way. I was also thinking about using a character formula to prove this, but to no avail thus far.

Comment: Once you know the multiplicities in the irrep $\Gamma_{a,b}$ (in Fulton-Harris notation), you can find the multiplicity in this picture because of the decomposition $Sym^a(V) \otimes Sym^b(V^*) = \oplus_{i=0}^{b} \Gamma_{a-i,b-i}$ Is your confusion with the multiplicities in $\Gamma_{a,b}$ ?

Comment: It could be that I'm misunderstanding the text, but I thought they used the result for $\mathrm{Sym}^a(V)\otimes \mathrm{Sym}^b(V^*)$ to deduce the result for $\Gamma_{a,b}$.

Comment: Ah! You are right. It needs a bit of calculation I think, first we know weight multiplicities in the standard representation(and it's dual), and from that we get weight multiplicities in $Sym^a$ and then tensor product.